# List in Scala with multiple types of elements

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm a beginner in Scala and have started playing with types.

I want to initialize an object D together with its value "myList" which is type of List. The List can have elements of type A and also B at the same time. Class A and B both extend class C. Val myList is not mandatory.

So I wrote:

```
class A extends C
class B extends C
class D(val myList : Option[List[T]] forSome { type T >: C } = None)

new D(Some(List(new A, new B)))
new D(Some(List(new A, new B)))
```

My question is, whether this is a proper way to do such a thing? Also, is it good practise to have values which can be of different types or is better to avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: I would say that heavily depends on the use case. Alternatives: Use empty-list instead of Some/None, Use Either[A,B] if you know you have exactly two type (and want to avoid casting when retrieving values).

Comment: isn't it more laconic to declare class D(val myList: Option[List[C]] = None) ?

Comment: `class D[T >: C](val myList: Option[List[T]] = Some(List()))` like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just define myList as List[C]

```
class A extends C
class B extends C
class D(val myList : Option[List[C]] = None)
new D(Some(List(new A, new B)))
new D(Some(List(new A, new B)))
```

Better version without Option[]:

```
class A extends C
class B extends C
class D(val myList : List[C] = List.empty[C])    
new D(List(new A, new B))
new D(List(new A, new B))
```

Even better version with case class:

```
case class A extends C
case class B extends C
case class D(myList : List[C] = List.empty[C])    
D(List(A(), B()))
D(List(A(), B()))
```